# How should I validate two-dimensional array in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I am new learner of laravel.Now I have to use the laravel validation in my project.The data from the form is two-dimensional array in the follwing format:

```
[['product_id'=>1, 'quantity'=>2], ['product_id' => 4, 'quantity'=>5]]
```

I need to validate every product_id, how should I write the validation rule?
thank you!

Comment: It is clearly mention in laravel doc, did you search for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will validate the `product_id` field of each associative array within the form data.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    '*.product_id' => // your validation rule
]);
```